# Multi-line documentation for bash inspired by lisp

Tags: string, documentation

I want to print some usage information for some functions.  I customarily use `echo` or `printf` for each line.

```
  echo "-V, --version"
  echo "   Display the version number and copyrights of the invoked tool."
  echo "-u, --usage"
  echo "   Provides brief information on how to use this tool."
  echo "-h, --help"
  echo "   Print a description of the command-line options understood by"
```

Recently I have been looking at list where one can set a long multi-line string instead.

```
(defun myfunc ()
  "-V, --version
   Display the version number and copyrights of the invoked tool.
-u, --usage
   Provides brief information on how to use this tool.
-h, --help
   Print a description of the command-line options understood by"

  (commands-here))
```

I would like to do the same (as in lisp) for printing documentation for bash
scripts.  What can I do to achieve the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a multiline string:

```
echo '
-V, --version
   Display the version number and copyrights of the invoked tool.
-u, --usage
   Provides brief information on how to use this tool.
-h, --help
   Print a description of the command-line options understood by
'
```

The downside with this way of formatting is the first blank line. You can avoid that at the expense of a little clarify by starting the first line of text immediately after the quote, and closing the quotes immediately after the last line of text:

```
echo '-V, --version
   Display the version number and copyrights of the invoked tool.
-u, --usage
   Provides brief information on how to use this tool.
-h, --help
   Print a description of the command-line options understood by'
```

Comment: Would you be so kind to modify h]the answer to use a string rather than a direct call to `echo`.

Comment: @Heime you know how to assign to a variable? `a='some text here …'` and then `printf '%s\n' "$a"`

Comment: Ok, I can just make a multiline quoted string.  Have seen that the newline is inserted automatically for each line without requiring `\n` at end of each line,

Answer (score 2):

Like this, using *here-doc*:

```
cat<<'EOF'
  "-V, --version
   Display the version number and copyrights of the invoked tool.
-u, --usage
   Provides brief information on how to use this tool.
-h, --help
   Print a description of the command-line options understood by"
EOF
```

Check `man bash | less +/here-doc`

Comment: Single-quote `'EOF'` where first used to avoid evaluation of the string. Not sure what those double-quotes are doing..?

Comment: Yes, but there's no variables/nothing to escape

Comment: Me, I'd use single quotes instead of doubles (or none) anywhere I wanted to be sure there was no evaluation. So `printf '%s\n' …` rather than `printf "%s\n" …`, and `<<'EOF'` rather than `<<EOF`, etc.